# Application of Markov Chain to Game of Life Board Game

Tags: probability, markov-chains, game-theory, markov-process

I need to calculate the expected outcomes for the [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_of_Life). I believe that if I multiply the probability of landing on a particular square with the payoff of said square and add up all these values, I can get the expected payoff for the entire path of the board, at least I *think* thats how I can calculate the expected outcome.

I was thinking of using a Markov Chain to calculate the probabilities of landing on the squares. I made the transition matrix P like so with each "state" corresponding to a square on the board ($s_1$ is the first square, $s_2$ is the second square, etc. The board forks in various places, but I would only be considering 1 path ata time for the transition matrix)

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1/10 & 1/10 & 1/10 & ... & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1/10 & 1/10 & ... & 0 \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

(Im using 1/10 because the spinner on the board game goes from 1-10)

The last state represents the end, which is "Millionaire acres" or the farm place (name's not important). It's an absorbing state so this is an absorbing Markov Chain. All the other squares are transient states (I believe, I'm still new to Markov Chains). According to my online research, I can find the probability of landing on transient state j from transient state i from the ij entry of the matrix H where

$$
H = (N - I)N_{dg}^{-1}
$$

N is the fundamental matrix and I is the identity matrix. Will adding up the columns from H give me the overall probability of landing on a certain square, for example, a square where there's a salary payoff? Or am I doing all of this incorrectly?

Any help that would clarify this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand the situation correctly, all of your games start with the player in the initial state.  So the first row of your matrix $H$ is all you need: the $i$-th entry in the first row tells you the probability of ever reaching the $i$-th state.

Comment: @MatthewConroy yes but the probability of reaching say the 18th sqaure will be 0 in the first row because the spinner only goes up to 10 in the game. I need to find the probability that a player will land on the 18th square. He could move 10-4-4 or 5-5-5-3 etc. There's a lot of different ways to land on the sqaure and a lot of ways to not; instead of counting by hand I thought maybe using Markov Chains could help me get the number more easily